# what is the code for reset the text field form?

Tags: html, css, button, textfield, reset

I want to set a button which allow the user to reset the contact form, is there any method to do it?

here is my coding for text field

```
            <div style="float:left;width:600px;"><!--textfield-->
                    <div style="float:left;">
                       <div style="float:left;width:90px;padding-top:5px">
                       NAME
                       </div>
                       <div style="float:left;padding-top:4px">
                       :
                            <input type="text" class="textfield"/>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                    <div style="float:left;padding-top:8px;">
                       <div style="float:left;width:90px;padding-top:5px">
                       EMAIL ADDRESS
                       </div>
                       <div style="float:left;padding-top:2px">
                       :
                            <input type="text" class="textfield"/>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                    <div style="float:left;padding-top:8px;">
                       <div style="float:left;width:90px;padding-top:5px">
                       CONTACT NUMBER
                       </div>
                       <div style="float:left;padding-top:2px">
                       :
                            <input type="text" class="textfield"/>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                    <div style="width:120p;float:left;padding-top:8px;">
                       <div style="float:left;width:90px;padding-top:5px">
                       MESSAGE
                       </div>
                       <div style="float:left;padding-top:2px">
                       :
                       </div>
                       <div style="float:left;margin-left:3px;padding-top:2px;">
                            <textarea cols="48" rows="6" class="textfield"></textarea>
                       </div>
                    </div>
            </div><!--textfield-->
        </div><!--end leave your personal details-->
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
        <div>
            <div id="buttonreset"><!--buttonreset-->
                <a href="#"><img src="img/buttonreset1.png" width="54" height="24" alt="reset" /></a>
            </div><!--end.buttonreset-->
            <div id="buttonsend"><!--buttonsend-->
                <a href="#"><img src="img/buttonsend1.png" width="54" height="24" alt="send" /></a>
            </div><!--end.buttonsend-->
        </div>
```

Css

```
    .textfield {
        font-family: CenturyGothic;
        font-size: 12px;
        color: #231F20;
        resize: none;
        text-align: left;
    }

    textarea {
        border: thin solid #221F1F;
        border-radius: 5px;
        width: 430px;
        height: 160px;
        opacity: 0.8;
    }

    input {
        border: thin solid #221F1F;
        border-radius: 4px;
        width: 430px;
        height: 21px;
        opacity: 0.7;
    }

    #buttonreset {
        margin-top: 5px;
        background-image: url(../img/buttonreset.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        height: 24px;
        width: 54px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-left: 410px;
        float:left;
    }

    #buttonreset img {
        -webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
        transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;    
        opacity:0;
    }

    #buttonreset img:hover {
        opacity:1;
        cursor:pointer;
        -webkit-animation-duration: 1s; 
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;  
        Chrome, and Safari */
    }
```

I haven't add any coding to my button, what code suitable for my button?

this is my fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/K5CJ4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<input type='reset'>
```

is the easiest method.

[Edit]

Since you're trying to reset the form using an image, the easiest way is to use the `reset()` method in Javascript. (No need for a library like jQuery). To accomplish this, I simply added a bit of javascript to your `<a>` tag in your form, as well as wrapped the entire example in `<form></form>` tags, giving it an id of `contactForm` .

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zNkT3/)

Comment: I am using image as my button, if I use this coding, my image can't be shown. Beside, it doesn't work... or can you show me the full coding? sorry that i just learn to use dreamweaver.

Answer (score 0):

use jQuery way to solve it. like this :

```
$("#buttonreset").click(function() { // div's id
                $("#txtField1").val("");
                $("#txtField2").val("");
});
```

Comment: I am using image as my button, if I use this coding, my image can't be shown. Beside, it doesn't work... or can you show me the full coding? sorry that i just learn to use dreamweaver.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use :

```
  <button type="reset" id="btnreset" value="Reset">Reset</button>
```

The button is a reset button (resets the form-data to its initial values)

```
#btnreset {
    background-image: url("http://www.ricksdailytips.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/reset-button.gif");
    border: 0 none;
    height: 204px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: I am using image as my button, if I use this coding, my image can't be shown. Beside, it doesn't work... or can you show me the full coding? sorry that i just learn to use dreamweaver.

Comment: You can set image in background of this button.

Comment: what is the coding? can you write the code based on my css? it will be more easy for me to understand, thanks

Comment: What issue you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to automate this, you could set it such that the page refreshes the entire page after a given number of seconds. use the meta tag:

`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="(enter number of seconds before refresh);url=thispage.html" />`